# Creating and inserting var into jQuery Child Selector ("parent > child")

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, parent-child, selector

I have been trying to create a variable and then insert it into Child Selector using jQuery i.e. $("parent > child")  with no luck.

I have included the entire applicable segment of jQuery code as reference, the overall idea is that when a navigation button is clicked, the class ".is-checked" is added to the navigation button ".nav-collapse". Each button is associated with a unique data-filter that is applied via jQuery Isotope.

The issue I am having is that later on in the code, I am then trying to correctly call out the associated checked navigation button's data-filter (using the var = sclass) and apply this as a selector via the Child Selector $("parent > child") but have been having trouble getting this to work.

Issue is with the last 2 lines of code:

```
$('.nav-collapse').on( 'click', 'button', function( event ) {
    var $target = $( event.currentTarget );
    $target.toggleClass('is-checked');
    var isChecked = $target.hasClass('is-checked');
    var filter = $target.attr('data-filter');
        if ( isChecked ) {
            addFilter( filter );

        } else {
            removeFilter( filter );
        }

        $grid.isotope({ filter: filters.join(',') });


        $(".masonry-image a").click(function(){

            var sclass = $('.nav-collapse.is-checked').children().attr('data-filter');

            $(" li." + sclass + " > a[href$='-hi.jpg']").addClass("fancybox-button")
```

...

However, if I change the selector "parent" to an existing selector li class="li class1", for example:

```
$(" li.class1 > a[href$='-hi.jpg']")
```

then the functionality I am going for works effectively, so I know I am on the right track. I have not been able to find any examples of creating a variable then inserting it as the parent within the selector, so I am not sure if my issue lies within how I have set up the selector, or how I have constructed the variable, or both.

```
        <nav class="nav-collapse">
            <ul>
                <li><button class="button" data-filter=".class1">Class 1</button></li>
                <li><button class="button" data-filter=".class2">Class 2</button></li>
                <li><button class="button" data-filter=".class3">Class 3</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <li class="masonry-image class1">
        <a href="images/shared/00001-hi.jpg">
        <img src="images/shared/00001.jpg" width="308" height="205" alt=""/>
        </a>
        </li>

        <li class="masonry-image class2">
        <a href="images/shared/00002-hi.jpg">
        <img src="images/shared/00002.jpg" width="308" height="205" alt=""/>
        </a>
        </li>
```

Comment: Do you just need to concatenate the string? `$(myVar + " > child-selector")`

Comment: Does doing this instead work?  `$("li" + sclass + " > a[href$='-hi.jpg']").addClass("fancybox-button")` because your data-filter already has a "." in it, you have reproduced the "." twice

Comment: Aaron, removing the "." alone does not work.

Comment: steel, I attempted to concatenate the string as follows:        `var list = "li"; var sclass = $('.nav-collapse.is-checked').children().attr('data-filter'); var myVar = list.concat(sclass);` with no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you even check your sclass? Console.log is your friend ;)

As .children only travels down 1 level it will only check the UL. It will never reach the button.

Try:

```
var sclass = $('.nav-collapse.is-checked').find("button").attr('data-filter');
```

Or:

```
var sclass = $('.nav-collapse.is-checked button').attr('data-filter');
```

EDIT: oops I misinterpreted your code, I think you need:

```
var sclass = $('.nav-collapse').find('.is-checked').attr('data-filter');
```

Or this (note the space!):

```
var sclass = $('.nav-collapse .is-checked').attr('data-filter');
```

For your last line of code remove the dot after the li, or remove the dots from the data-filters.

Comment: Both of the last options you identified ended up working. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Yeah, at first I thought you were adding classes to the nav itself, which I later realised didn't make sense.